# Respond a JSON object in Postman using an Azure Function on JS / Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-functions, postman

I'm currently learning **Azure Functions** in my Back-end development. The problem is that using **Azure Functions** prevents my **JavaScript** code to return a simple JSON object in **Postman**. I've read the documentation and also tried using some JS functions like *JSON.Stringify*, but still no luck. Here's the sample of my code:

```
message = {
   success: true,
   status: 'pending',
   message: "Some message etc..."
}
return message;
```

I'm practically new to Azure, so any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ...

```
// Construct response
const responseJSON = {
    "name": "Some name",
    "sport": "Some sport",
    "message": "Some message",
    "success": true
}

context.res = {
    // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
    body: responseJSON,
    contentType: 'application/json'
};
```

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot man! :D